# How does population size affect sampling?

Tags: probability, sampling

I have two components: a service (creates logs) and a logger (writes logs to datastore)

The writing mechanism  of the logger is sampled: the logger writes only in 1 in 10 logs to the datastore

A log is just a piece of string - eg: "foo"

In my application, there is a **population** of 1M possible unique strings.

Say my service produced 100 logs every second.

1. Can I be assured that every generated log would be logged to the datastore?  What is the likelihood that a generated log would never be written to the datastore?
2. What if the population size increased to 1B - would the likelihood still be same?

Intuitively, to me it, it seems like if the population size *decreased*, the likelihood of all logs generated by the service would increase.

I am a complete dummy, so would appreciate some guidance on how to think about such problems :)

Comment: I don't see any way to answer your first question, since we don't know the probability distribution of these strings.  It could be that some strings are extremely rare, and others are very common (e.g. the string "everything is fine" might be very common, while "aliens are invading the Earth!" might be very, very rare).  As such, there is no way to know ho likely it is for any particular string to be written to the database.  For your second question, sure---if there are more strings, it is probably less likely that any one string will get written.  But, again, what is the distribution?

Comment: @XanderHenderson that's a good point, let's assume it is a uniform distribution of generated strings.